# gluegen.jar ; error while compiling zip file

Tags: java, graphics, jogl, java-3d, multi-agent

I am trying to set up MASON multi agent simulation software on OSX which requires me to install Java3d libraries. I have installed gluegen.jar from http://jogamp.org/deployment/. While compiling, it gives the following error

error reading /Library/Java/Extensions/gluegen.jar; error in opening zip file

I have experimented with various versions of jogamp/deployment for the same but error remains the same.

Comment: Seems you might need to include much much more detail. For one thing, we have no idea what sort of system setup you have and another, there is no file at that link with the name `gluegen.jar`. Presumably you downloaded one of the many versions, but we don't know which one. And we don't know what system commands you submitted.

Comment: Please follow my detailed instructions http://gouessej.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/java-3d-est-de-retour-java-3d-is-back/

Comment: Thank You. I downloaded v2.0.2 -> jar -> glugen.jar in OSX Sierra 10.12. I compiled the makefile which shows an error in opening glugen.jar

Comment: You should use a more recent version of JOGL. You should rather use the single fat JAR jogamp-fat.jar and when it didn't exist in earlier versions, the developers used gluegen-rt.jar as gluegen.jar is useless in third party libraries in most of the case. Please strictly follow my instructions and stop copying JARs into /Library/Java/Extensions/ as it's a bad practice, which is explained in my tutorial.